# Stop Windows 10 from automatically downloading (promoted) apps

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui

A newly installed Windows 10 (since ver 1511) has some non-installed, promoted apps pinned to Start Menu, and as soon as you connect to internet Windows starts downloading and installing them (from Windows Store). This procedure runs every time a new user is created and I have to uninstall them one by one. So is there a way to stop this?

I also installed some apps manually from Windows Store, and I enjoy Windows' auto-update feature. So it would be better if this feature can be preserved while disabling auto-installation.

Comment: This might help : [Disabling auto update on all Store apps Win10](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-automatic-updates-for-windows-store-apps-in-windows-10)

Comment: @Vylix I already Googled before asking this question.

Comment: Nice! You are always encouraged to post your research on your question, so future visitor will know if a specific solution does not work on your particular question. So, to clarify, is your main question "How to selectively stop Store apps auto-update?" or "How to disable Store apps auto-update for all (future) users?"

Comment: And it will be helpful to include the edition of Windows 10 you are using (Home, Pro, Enterprise)

Comment: @Vylix Decided to post an answer instead, though :) Because too many is found.

Comment: Welcome to Windows 10, it will change your life....

Comment: @Moab I'm a Windows 10 User since January 2015, when TP build 9926 was just released.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[A Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Prevent+Windows+10+Install+Apps) gives quite a lot of solutions. Here are some of them. Categorized.

### Settings Changes

- Metro Settings App

  - Navigate to **Personalization >  Start**
  - Turn off **Occasionally show suggestions in Start**

    > This method has limited functionality - it doesn't stop the apps who already have a tile on the start screen from downloading, but only stop new promotional tiles from appearing.
- Windows Store App

  - Click your avatar on top right, to the left of the search box. In the drop-down menu, click **Settings**
  - Find **Update apps automatically**, turn that off

    > This will disable auto-update for installed apps!

---

### Group Policy Changes

> Note: Local Group Policy Editor is not available in **Windows 10 Home Edition** and **Windows 10 S**. The following methods are available only in **Windows 10 Professional**, **Enterprise** and **Education** editions.

> Note: This will disable auto-update for installed apps!

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor by pressing <kbd>**Win**</kbd>+<kbd>**R**</kbd> and typing **`gpedit.msc`** in the dialog, then hit "OK"
2. In the left pane, navigate to **Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Store**
3. In the right pane of **Store** in Local Group Policy Editor, double click/tap on **Turn off Automatic Download and Install of updates** policy to edit it.
4. Click on **Not configured**. In the drop-down menu, select **Always**

---

### Registry Tweaks

> Note: Applying only **one** tweak is enough. You can, however, apply multiple tweaks at the same time, unnecessarily.

1. Open Registry Editor by pressing <kbd>**Win**</kbd>+<kbd>**R**</kbd> and typing **`regedit.exe`** in the dialog, then hit "OK"
2. Select an option from below. Navigate to the key and add/change the value

   - Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CloudContent`
     *If this key does not exist, create it.*
     Create a new **DWORD** value named `DisableWindowsConsumerFeatures` and set to **1**

     > This will also disable **Windows Spotlight** setting for lockscreen!
   - Key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ContentDeliveryManager`
     Find the value `SilentInstalledAppsEnabled` and set to **0**
     *This is the **recommended** solution. However you need to do this once for each user.*
   - Key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore`
     Find the value `AutoDownload` and set to **2**

     > This will disable auto-update for installed apps!